# If else branch never used

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, messagedialog

I'm using if else and writing down some codes suddenly happens the else said the branch is never used... but it should work.

The statement looks like this

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,full_name+"\n"+number_age+"\n"+gender+"\n"+address+
                 "\n"+birthday+"\n"+cell_no,"CHECK INFORMATION!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if(true){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for Entering");
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Retry");
}
```

Comment: How should the else branch ever be processed if if true is never false?

Comment: Can you give us one example of a situation for which this: if(true){  would return false?

Comment: If the button No or Cancel is push the pop up message should activate "Please Retry" but in my case it wont trigger I think because of the dead branch in else

Comment: You may want to check the result of the dialog box instead of just the value `true`.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: If you won’t accept any response but “OKAY,” why are you allowing other choices as option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) response and compare with `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`:

```
int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,full_name+"\n"+number_age+"\n"+gender+"\n"+address+
                 "\n"+birthday+"\n"+cell_no,"CHECK INFORMATION!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == answer)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for Entering");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Retry");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be if (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == answer))  ?

Comment: I did this and it work, Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: @jasperianpalma you welcome, you can accept the answer by clicking on *V* Sign to the left

Comment: @user7294900 I ment YES_OPTION instead of YES_NO_OPTION. Yes, they are both "0" but YES_OPTION would be more correct imho. Don't even know if both are "0" in all Java implementations.